# Why Neo4j index not working with order by?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

why neo4j order by is very slow for large database :(

here is the example query:

```
PROFILE MATCH (n:Item) RETURN n ORDER BY n.name Desc LIMIT 25
```

and in result it's read all records but i already used index on name property.

here is the result

[Click here to see results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0Y5J.png)

it reads all nodes, it's real mess for large number of records.

any solution for this?

or neo4j is not good choice too for us :(

and any way to get last record from nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Your question and problem are not very clear.

1) Are you sure that you added the index correctly?

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Item(name)
```

In the Neo4j browser execute `:schema` to see all your indexes.

2) How many Items does your database hold and what running time are you expecting and achieving?

3) What do you mean by 'last record from nodes'?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are currently only used to find entry points into the graph, but not for other uses including ordering of results.

Indexed-backed ORDER BY operations have been a [highly requested feature for awhile](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/6584), and while we've been tracking and ordering its priority, we've had several other features that took priority over this work.

I believe indexed-backed ORDER BY operations are currently scheduled very soon, for our 3.5 release coming in the last few months of 2018.